# Ionic5 Angular - transform http reponse to custom object

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, httpclient

I'm completely new to Ionic and angular and I'm trying to load data from a REST api (for testing a local json file) and transform them to an object as the origin json structure is not really useful.

I tried this:

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
  var data = this.locationService.getLocalData()
  console.log(data);
}
```

location.service.ts:

```
getLocalData() {
let url = "/assets/data/locallocations.json";
 this.http.get<any[]>(url).subscribe(result => {
  var locations: Array<Location> = [];
      result.forEach(element => {
        try {
          var location: Location = new Location;
          location.id = element.station["id"];
          location.name = element.station["name"];
          location.number = element.station["number"];
          location.longitude = element.station["geocoordinate"]["longitude"];
          location.latitude = element.station["geocoordinate"]["latitude"];
          locations.push(location);
          
        } catch(error){
        }
      })
      console.log(locations)
    return locations

});
}
```

in the ngAfterViewInit() the console log is always undefinied (but not in the getLocalData()) - could somebody help me creating the getLocalData function in a way that I can also subscribe on it and wait for the result? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the community! If Locations is an Array, you have to use array.push() on the results. But for a simple way to get results in your service, you may try like this:

```
   getLocalData(){
    let url = '/assets/data/locallocations.json';
    fetch(url).then(res => res.json())
    .then(result => {
        console.log('Locations: ', result);
    });
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you: I have found (another) solution for it:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.locationService.GetLocations().subscribe(result => {
      console.log(result)
   })
}
```

location.service.ts:

```
GetLocations(): Observable<any> {
return new Observable((observer: Observer<any>) => {
  let url = '/assets/data/locallocations.json';
  this.fetchLocalData().then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
      var data = this.processData(res).subscribe(res => {
        observer.next(res);
        observer.complete();
      })
    });
})
}

processData(data): Observable<any> {
return new Observable((observer: Observer<any>) => {

  var locations: Location[] = [];
  data.forEach(element => {
    try {
      var location: Location = new Location;
      location.id = element.station["id"];
      location.name = element.station["name"];
      location.number = element.station["number"];
      location.longitude = element.station["geocoordinate"]["longitude"];
      location.latitude = element.station["geocoordinate"]["latitude"];
      locations.push(location);
    } catch (error) {
    }
  })
  observer.next(locations);
  observer.complete();
})
}

fetchLocalData(){
   let url = '/assets/data/locallocations.json';
      return fetch(url);
}
```